# Finding max value of Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have two classes, DataClass and MY GUI Class.

This is in my GUI Class

```
 final ArrayList<DataClass> MarksData = new ArrayList<DataClass>();
```

I store 4 elements at a time `[Mark1,Mark2,Mark3,Mark4]`

How can I find all the maximum mark for `Mark1`

I tried `Object obj = Collections.min()` but doesn't work since it's an `arrayList` of type `DataClass`.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: how do you determine what is the maximum mark?

Comment: What are `Mark1`, `Mark2`, and so on...? Show us the source code of `DataClass`.

Comment: simply traverse the list , take a temp variable storing the first array value , compare the two adjacent , if higher value is found replace it to temp var , in the end the temp var returns the max value , this is simple sorting algo

Comment: @RohitJain Here is my dataClass http://pastebin.com/jfsuydQG

Comment: @JamesHunter.. That link is not accessible in my office. You should post your code here. Try to extract relevant part and post taht.

Comment: @RohitJain I've updated the question with my simple data class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this would probably be to use `Collections.max()`, but to do this you need to implement [`Comparable<DataClass>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) on the `DataClass` class.

This interface lets you define a `compareTo(DataClass o)` method where you can write the logic in that method to determine if it's less or greater than the other mark, and then `Collections.max()` will take care of finding the maximum for you.

As noted in the comment, you can also write a custom comparator and use the variant of `Collections.max()` which takes that custom comparator - but the logic you write to compare the marks is the same.

Note that if you want to find the minimum mark instead, go for `Collections.min()`. All other details remain the same.

Comment: Or you can also write a Comparator. and use max(Collection coll, Comparator comp)

Comment: The question says "maximum mark" but it appears the OP wants the minimum which could be the "best mark"

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good point, missed that. Added a note about `min()` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

To use Collections.min() you must either make `DataClass implements Comparable<DataClass>` or you must provide a custom `Comparator<DataClass>`